# why the default color of type (let, var, func) off, and It crash my app - CS193

Tags: swift, calculator

[I am learning from the online resource, CS193 and I was programming the calculator.I followed every step and trying to run the program.

And I find that there had only one things is different, and it end up crash my app.

The default color of type "let" was off, and it suppose to be in PINK color.
(let value, let function)

```
func performOperation (symbol: String) {
    if let operation = operations[symbol] {
    switch operation {
    case .Constant(let value): accumulator = value
    case .UnaryOperation(let function): accumulator = function(accumulator)
    case .BinaryOperation(let function): pending = PendingBinaryOperationInfo(binaryFunction: function, firstOperand: accumulator)
```

My question is "why this is happening? it should be every time I type "let" and the default color pink is on.

I type the same things as the professor did, and when I run the program, using the key "π", then it crash. and it show it's error in the same area

Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1

Please find the print screen picture here thanks ~>][PrintscreenPicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZke1.png)

Comment: What error is being thrown when the app crashes ?

Comment: @CoderMike, he just put breakpoint and now thinks it's a crash.

Comment: 1) A course number is of little use without context. Please give a reference to the task that we can actually follow. 2) You should probably do the homework on your own.

Comment: @user28434 oh i see, thanks